# Combine columns from two tables

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables like:

```
Table A             Table B
+---------------+   +------------------------------+    
| ID   NAME     |   | ID    TYPE       DATE        |    
+---------------+   +------------------------------+    
| 001    A      |   | 001    URGE     2024-01-01   |    
| 002    B      |   | 001    UPDATE   2024-01-02   |
| 003    C      |   | 002    UPDATE   2024-01-03   |
+---------------+   | 001    URGE     2023-12-30   |
                    +------------------------------+
```

And my expected results is:

```
   +-------------------------------------+    
   | ID    NAME   TYPE       DATE        |    
   +-------------------------------------+    
   | 001    A    URGE     2024-01-01     |    
   | 002    B    -        -              |
   | 003    C    -        -              |
   +-------------------------------------+
```

I want to select the all the results in Table A and join table B with condition "TYPE = 'URGE'" and output the most recent DATE, otherwise the DATE column output NULL. How should I write the SQL?

Comment: You need an outer join - have you even tried anything?? What about your current attempt is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
SELECT
    A.ID,
    A.NAME,
    CASE WHEN B.TYPE = 'URGE' THEN B.TYPE ELSE '-' END AS TYPE,
    CASE WHEN B.TYPE = 'URGE' THEN B.DATE ELSE NULL END AS DATE
FROM
    TableA A
LEFT JOIN
    TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.TYPE = 'URGE';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
  SELECT
        A.ID,
        A.NAME,
        B.TYPE,
        B.DATE
    FROM
    TableA A LEFT JOIN
    (select * from TableB where TYPE='URGE') B 
    ON A.ID = B.ID ;
```

Comment: Why the subquery? Just put the condition in the `ON`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, COALESCE(B.TYPE, '-') AS TYPE, COALESCE(B.DATE, '-') AS DATE 
FROM TableA A 
LEFT JOIN TableB B 
    ON A.ID = B.ID 
   AND B.TYPE = 'URGE'
```

Comment: Note _otherwise the DATE column output NULL_.

Comment: Could use some explanation instead of just a SQL statement.